# Как с помощью макросов проверить какой у тебя компилятор и версия языка?

Tags: c++

Как с помощью макросов проверить какой у тебя компилятор и версия языка?

Comment: BOOST можно использовать?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian желательно стандартными методами

Comment: Стандарт про это ничего не говорит к сожалению.

Comment: Если в коде есть места, которые жестко связаны с используемым компилятором, используйте конструкции подобные этой: ```#if defined( _MSC_VER > ... ) ... #elif defined( __GNUC__ > N ) ... #endif``` Возможно, поможет )))

Comment: Вот здесь посмотрите: https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Home/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Каждый конкретный компилятор определяет свои собственные макросы; общих макросов, которые могут указать компилятор, нет.

Что касается версии языка, то есть предопределенные макросы типа `__STDC__` или `__STDC_VERSION__`, но их конкретные значения отданы на откуп реализациям.

Например, из стандарта:

> _ _ STDC_VERSION _ _
>   Whether _ _ STDC_VERSION _ _ is predefined and if so, what its value is, are implementation-defined.

Так что лучше смотреть документации к разным компиляторам и собирать макросы, определенные в них. А потом проверять - если такой макрос есть, значит, это вот такой компилятор, а версия его вот такая... Типа `_MSC_VER` в Visual C++.

Comment: а `__cplusplus`?

Comment: А он не говорит ничего о компиляторе и его версии. Теоретически в драфте стандарта написано `The name _ _ cplusplus is defined to the value 201103L when compiling a C++ translation unit.`, но, например VC++ 2015 дает его значение 199711...

Comment: @Harry, но версию языка то, по-идее, с его помощью он определить может. Только зачем ? Типа C++03 - используем в std::find кастомные предикаты, C++11 - можем лямбды заюзать..Вроде глупости..(

Comment: `определенные предопределенные` определённо

Comment: @alexolut Не то язык заплетается, не то клавиатура :)